# how do i mirror image a design on a 4 x 6 grid?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-trace

i need to make a design for the back of a playing card. i have done it manually by using tracing paper ! but need to do it on photoshop so its quicker. basically I'm using the 4 card pack images, clubs, diamond, heart, spade in one 4cm sq & mirror imaging it.  in the corners i am mirror imaging it on a diagonal, ie only tracing 1/2 the image on the diagonal corner & mirror imaging it within the same square. 
not sure that im explaining well, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Create a smart object

Duplicate the Smart Object layer 3 times and rotate /position each copy accordingly.

Edit the smart object by double-clicking it in the Layers Panel.

Whenever you save the edits to the smart object, the duplicate smart object layers will update as well.